# Print out multi-level unordered list via Ruby and CSV

Tags: html, ruby, csv

This might be a backwards way of doing this. I have a bit of code that reads a CSV file and prints the results in a HTML file.  I would like to have this file printed out as an unordered list if at all possible.

This is what I have now and its output is not what I want:

```
require 'csv'

 col_data = [] 
 CSV.foreach("primary_NAICS_code.txt") {|row| col_data << row} 

begin
  file = File.open("primary_NAICS_code_html.html", "w")
  col_data.each do |row|
    indentation, (text,*) = row.slice_before(String).to_a
    file.write(indentation.fill("<ul>").join(" ") + "<il>" + text+ "</il></ul?\n")
  end
rescue IOError => e
 puts e
ensure
  file.close unless file == nil
end
```

Comment: What does the output look like? How do you want it to look? How about some sample CSV? "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance."

Answer (score 1):

- Unordered lists aren't surrounded by `<ul> ... </ul?`.  Question marks don't make HTML happy.
- List items are `<li>` tags, not `<il>`.
- You need to keep track of your depth to know if you need to add `<ul>` tags or can just add more items.

Try this:

```
require 'csv'

col_data = [] 
 CSV.foreach("primary_NAICS_code.txt") {|row| col_data << row} 

begin
  file = File.open("primary_NAICS_code_html.html", "w")
  file.write('<ul>')
  depth = 1
  col_data.each do |row|
    indentation, (text,*) = row.slice_before(String).to_a
    if indentation.length > depth
      file.write('<ul>')
    elsif indentation.length < depth
      file.write('</ul>')
    end
    file.write("<li>" + text+ "</li>")
    depth = indentation.length
  end
  file.write('</ul>')
rescue IOError => e
  puts e
ensure
  file.close unless file == nil
end
```

It's not very pretty but it seems to work.

Comment: thank you. this helps a lot.  While it works  several hundred lines of code down it stats to just keep indenting over and over.